# how to get user's address using address api of google play services 4.3 in android?

Tags: android, google-play-services

In the google i/o 2014 there was a vast introduction of new Google play services APIs. I learned that there is an API called address by which users don't have to put their address manually and this API will take all the information dynamically from his/her gmail account.

In my project I just want to set the address in a TextView but I didn't find any single tutorial on it over the internet. I have set the google play service library as a library project in my project but I cant do further on this occasion, any help?

Comment: but in the API releases there is a distinct APi called Address API which is not belongs to WALLET as far as I know

Comment: Have a look at the bottom
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/03/google-play-services-43.html

Comment: Can you help me on this, just want to get the addresses as string using the API @tyczj

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this post from Android Developer blogspot to get more details

http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2014/03/google-play-services-43.html

I searched lot for the same you want, there is no details available except the package details and this blog post,

In the post they have mentioned

> That’s it for this time. Now go to work and incorporate these new features to make your apps even better!
>   And stay tuned for future updates.

I think they will come up with the tutorial and documentation in near future

**Update:** I got a hint from the the Google Opensource wallet sample, 
You can get the the idea when you look at this file thoroughly

https://github.com/googlewallet/instantbuy-android/blob/f3ed08dfc13d843fe15c397c72df440ba32309e8/src/com/google/android/gms/samples/wallet/PromoAddressLookupFragment.java

I created a sample app based on this file and succeeded.

Comment: Thank you, still searching for the answer, I will review your links

Comment: Ok I have done exact the same as it is, but I am not geting RESULT_OK in the onActivityResult. I dont understand where is the problem